# php obstacle when index page restarting Automatically

Tags: php, restart

I have a script that I can get the YouTube videos

```
$path_to_file = realpath('index.txt');
$videolink = @file_get_contents($path_to_file);


if(isset($videolink))
{
include('curl.php');
include('youtube.php');
$tube = new youtube();
$links = $tube->get($videolink);
```

But sometimes it does not show result So I do something like this:

```
if(!$links) {
go back and try again
```

when script goes to back and starts again, php makes many errors like "Cannot redeclare function" and ...

what can i do?

If you need more information please tell me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

May be when your code go back. It includes curls.php and youtube.php again. In this case, replacing `include` with `include_once` might enough.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930646/cannot-redeclare-function-php)
might help you.