# php include multiple file with same function name

Tags: php, function, include

I have 3 php file
index.php file contain following code

```
<?php
include ('file1.php');
include ('file2.php')
?>
```

file1.php contain

```
function aa(){
    sleep(5);
    return 2;
}
function bb(){
    sleep(5);
    return 1;
}
echo bb();
echo aa();
setStartTrigger($AutoID,3,$db_automation);
```

file2.php contain same function

```
function aa(){
    sleep(5);
    return 2;
}
function bb(){
    sleep(5);
    return 1;
}
echo bb();
echo aa();
setStartTrigger($AutoID,3,$db_automation);
```

the output return error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare aa() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\automation_kickoff\file2.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\automation_kickoff\file1.php on line 5
```

i want something without changing any of my function name

Comment: why don't you want to change the function name ? when you do the 2 include, there's 2 times the same function name, so if you call it on the 3rd php page there will be a conflict...

Comment: including 2 absolutely identical php files? for what? : )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot redeclare function php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930646/cannot-redeclare-function-php)

Comment: Didi: because sometimes you do not have the choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Namespaces starting from PHP 5.3.

file2.php

```
namespace A;

function aa(){
    sleep(5);
    return 2;
}
function bb(){
    sleep(5);
    return 1;
}

namespace {
    echo A\bb();
    echo A\aa();

    setStartTrigger($AutoID,3,$db_automation);
}
```

and file2.php

```
namespace B;

function aa(){
    sleep(5);
    return 2;
}
function bb(){
    sleep(5);
    return 1;
}

namespace {
    echo B\bb();
    echo B\aa();

    setStartTrigger($AutoID,3,$db_automation);
}
```